# replacing special characters using SED

Tags: regex, sed, pcre

I am having following fields and using SED i need to remove special characters to remove [ ] with space

```
Retrieve [File
Monitor [FW] end
Monitor [FW] start
Monitor [DR] end
Monitor DR] start
Open File
Set Password
Logon
Logoff
Monitor Backup] end
Monitor Backup] start
Auto Clear] History end
Auto Clear] History start
Old [Backup Deletion End
```

I have used following SED command

```
 "s/(\[\w+\])|(\w+\[)|(\w+\])/ /g"
```

But it is skipping the one with no special characters

Comment: `sed` does not use PCRE regex engine. Why not replace the brackets with `sed 's/[][]/ /g'`? What is the expected result? Try `sed -E 's/\s*(\[\w+]?|\[?\w+])\s*/ /g'` then

Comment: If you need a working answer, please explain what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. sed 's/[][]/ /g' worked.

Comment: "All characters are special." -- [tchrist](/users/471272/tchrist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/[][]/ /g' file > newfile
```

The `[][]` pattern matches a `[` or `]` and `g` makes `sed` replace all occurrences on a line.

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/R1l4ZE).